# How does the author of this probability book claim that a one-to-one function is invertible without showing it's onto?

Tags: probability

I know that the necessary conditions for a function to be invertible is that the function must be onto. I'm not sure how the author can just assume that the function $u(x)$ is onto.

[image]

Comment: Although the context doesn't seem to give a lot of clues, perhaps they mean an inverse function $v$ on the image of $u$ (where $u$ *is* onto).

Comment: I agree with @Hayden. You only need $v$ on the domain of $Y$, which is exactly the image of $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is not up to modern standards in his treatment of functions:

(1) No mention is made of the domain or codomain of any function.

(2) The notation used muddles a function $f$ with its value $f(x)$ at a general point $x$.

It seems to be left to the reader to work out what the domain and range are for any function that is treated. When you have ascertained these for a one-to-one function, you can of course construct the inverse function from the range of the original function to its domain.

Comment: I agree with you that the author is not very precise, but it's probably quite clear from the context that $u$ is a partial function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, the (left-)inverse function that you can construct can be defined on the whole codomain of $u$, not just on its range.

Answer (score 2):

> **Definition.** Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. A function $f \colon A \to B$ is called *invertible* if it has an *inverse*, i.e. if there exists $g \colon B \to A$ such that $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$ **and** $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_B$.
>
> **Proposition.** A function is invertible if and only if it is bijective.

Now:

> **Definition.** Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. A function $f \colon A \to B$ is called *left-invertible* if it has a *left-inverse*, i.e. if there exists $g \colon B \to A$ such that $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$.
>
> **Proposition.** A function is left-invertible if and only if it is injective.

and similarly

> **Definition.** Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. A function $f \colon A \to B$ is called *right-invertible* if it has a *right-inverse*, i.e. if there exists $g \colon B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_B$.
>
> **Proposition.** A function is right-invertible if and only if it is surjective.

Note that $\operatorname{id}_A$ is the identity function on $A$.

So basically the author of your book should have written "left-inverse" instead of just "inverse", but this is often omitted, especially since he also makes it clear by writing "so that $v(u(x))=x$", which means exactly $v \circ u = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R}$.

Bonus: to prove the last proposition you need the [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). Actually, the statement in the last proposition is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. If someone could explain the reason, I'd be happy to fix my answer or to delete it.